# How can I prevent a specific shared library from loading?

Tags: python, c++, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a (C++) program that utilizes wxWidgets and GTK2 under Linux.  I also have some basic Python scripting using the Python C-API (https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html).

I'm running into a problem where `PyRun_SimpleString("import wx\n");` segfaults when running under Ubuntu 18.04 but runs fine under Ubuntu 16.04.  The issue appears to be that Ubuntu 18.04 does not package `wxpython-gtk2`.  It only provides `wxpython-gtk3`.

Using strace, I find that the python api imports wx, which in turn loads `wxpython`, pulling in GTK3 and shadowing all of the GTK2 function calls.

**Question:** Any ideas for how I can prevent GTK3 from being loaded as a dependency for my program?

Long-term, I'm moving to GTK3 and phoenix but that's a ways off...

Comment: you can recompile with GTK+3. Or you can install wxPython for GTK+2 (either manually or from the repo). Or you can select GTK+2 as a main library using pkg-config. Up to you....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Unfortunately, wxPython for GTK+2 is not available under Ubuntu 18.04. I can compile my own but makes it hard to distribute.  Porting to GTK3 is in the works but is a long-term project.